# iMovie won't import text overlay from My Media

Tags: imovie

I'm trying to use video footage from security camera in iMovie. The clip I'm trying to import is mp4, and has some sort of text overlay which shows time and date. I can import it fine and it shows in My Media, and when I play it in iMovie it's visible as well, however as soon as I drag the clip to timeline, it's gone and I can't work with it.

I thought that time and date are encoded into video, but they are obviously overlaid in some way - I suspect that it's added through ffmpeg drawtext filter.

Is there a way to use this text overlay in my movie?